# Angular4 npm start issues

Tags: angular

I am trying to run command npm start, before that I installed nodejs, npm install.  Following issues has been attached in image file.
[image]

Please have a greatful help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you see tells that you run npm install from a directory that doesn't have the file package.json.

Also, you have a very old version of Node. Angular requires at least the version 6.9. Install the current version of Node from https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `packages.json` file. When you start a project run `npm init` to create one.

For Angular there is a small program "Angular CLI" to create complete projects with all dependencies.

https://cli.angular.io/